# Allow numbers and enter only on content editable div keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, numbers, enter

Hey guys i'm creating a content editable div and it should accept numbers and enter key only on every key press is it possible? Thanks

**Update**

```
if(event.keyCode >= 48 || event.keyCode <= 57){
   if ( event.keyCode == 13 ) {
   }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

On my code it's accepting numbers only but not the enter key.

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: how? i update my question

Comment: What have you already tried? StackOverflow is not a drive-thru code generation service.

Comment: updated my question with my current code

Comment: As of writing, your code asks for key codes either >= 48 or <= 57. That should be AND, not OR.

Answer (score 2):

Proper code is:

```
if ((event.keyCode >== 48 && event.keyCode <== 57) || event.keyCode === 13) {
  // do something with this information
} else {
  return false;
}
```

You are expecting key (between 48 **AND** 57) **OR** 13. Problem was that your first condition is between 48 and 57 and then you check for 13 inside that block, which would mean **between 48 and 57 and exactly 13** which is impossible situation.

Answer (score 2):

Just put this in any tag( ie.`<span>`)...

```
onKeypress="if(event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57){return false;}"
```

and it will not accept any characters.